# File android , add to the file after creating

Tags: android, eclipse, file

hello i have this code :

```
protected void createFile(String Text) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("mynote2.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(Text.getBytes());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Comment Added succesfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("CreateFile", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CreateFile", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                // drain the stream
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am making a comment system , i want to enter comments , when someone write a comment then press the button the comment is created and a new file is created "mynote2.txt" but when i enter the code again , it doesn't save it into the file , it create it once again with the last comment edited , and I want to enter it to the file not to create a new file

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your `openFileOutput("mynote2.txt", MODE_PRIVATE)` method you'll be creating a new `FileoutputStream` object. Use this `FileOutputStream (File file, boolean append)` constructor and give 2nd parameter as true and it'll append data to your existing file.